# Macbook Pro 16 inch keyboard light wont turn on in bootcamp windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, macbook, boot-camp

Whenever I use Windows on my MacBook I can't turn on the light on my keyboard and it's tough because when it gets dark I want to see my keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Apple [knowledge base article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/bootcamp-control-panel/bcmpa0d98882/mac) on this issue:

1. In Windows on your Mac, click the show hidden icons arrow in the right side of the taskbar, click the Boot Camp icon, then choose Boot Camp Control Panel.
2. If a User Account Control dialog appears, click Yes.
3. Click Keyboard.
4. Do any of the following:

- Automatically turn off keyboard backlighting after a period of inactivity: Drag the “Turn off keyboard backlight when computer is not used for” slider to the desired setting.
- Automatically change keyboard brightness in low light: Select the “Adjust keyboard brightness in low light” checkbox.